# Converting a string to a defined constant in PHP

Tags: php, string, constants

Let's say I have defined the constant `ERROR_0` as follows:

```
define("ERROR_0","An error occurred.")
```

Now, let's say I have the string "ERROR_0" but I want to convert that into the constant `ERROR_0` such that I can get the string "An Error occurred."  How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: The function is [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use [`constant`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function

```
echo constant("ERROR_0");
```