# Echo defined constant depending on variable without if() in PHP

Tags: php, constants

The title might be a bit confusing, but w/e.
Is it possible to do something like this?

```
define('test_1', 'test1');
define('test_2', 'test2');
define('test_3', 'test3');
$test='2';
echo test_$test;
```

I simply want to echo one of those defined constants (in this case 2) depending on what $test is, without using if() or switch().

Comment: view this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592707/converting-a-string-to-a-defined-constant-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be sorted with the following:

```
echo constant('test_'.$test);
```